# pyspark Window function find previous that also matches on other column

Tags: pyspark

I have data that looks like

```
user | type | fld | time | idA | idB
jo      B     4     1:00  ---   454
jo      A     4     1:01  302   ---
jo      B     3     1:02  ---   123
jo      B     6     2:34  ---   345
jo      A     3     4:33  764   ---
bob     B     2     1:02  ---   965
bob     A     2     1:10  502   ---
```

for each user, there are A and B records, and they each have timestamps. For each A record, I want to find the corresponding B record. This will be the most recent previous B record that matches on the 'fld' column. That is from the above, I want to produce

```
user | type | fld | time | idA | idB | prev_idB
jo      B      4    1:00  ---   454   ---
jo      A      4    1:01  302   ---   454
jo      B      3    1:02  ---   123   ---
jo      B      6    2:34  ---   345   ---
jo      A      3    4:33  764   ---   123
bob     B      2    1:02  ---   965   ---
bob     A      2    1:10  502   ---   965
```

Can I do this with Window functions in pyspark? I'm sure I could do this if I dropped down to the rdd interface, keyed everything by user, aggregated all the user records, sorted by time, and started walking the list, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using SQL Window functions. I imagine I would partition by user, order by time - but then I want a function that, for A records, pulls the previous record that

- has type B
- has fld == the fld of this A record

and I don't care what it does for B records.

It seems too complicated for the Window functions I've read about, because of the matching of other columns.

I could probably drop the 'has type B' requirement, since there should always be at least one 'B' record between two 'A' records, but data might be imperfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that makes use of 2 windows and 1 join: let's call your data `df` as a pyspark dataframe,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('user', 'fld').orderBy(col('time').desc())
w2 = Window.partitionBy('user', 'fld', 'type').orderBy(col('time').desc()) 

df_group = df.withColumn('row_group', 
                          row_number().over(w1) - row_number().over(w2))
```

Here, `df_group` looks like

```
user | type | fld | time | idA | idB | row_group
jo      B     4     1:00  ---   454    1
jo      A     4     1:01  302   ---    0
jo      B     3     1:02  ---   123    1
jo      B     6     2:34  ---   345    0
jo      A     3     4:33  764   ---    0
bob     B     2     1:02  ---   965    1
bob     A     2     1:10  502   ---    0
```

The most recent rows you wanted all have `row_group = 1`. If you filter on `row_group` and join it back to df

```
df_group = (df_group
         .filter('row_group=1')
         .select('user', 'fld', col('idB').alias('prev_idB')))

df_result = df.join(df_group, on=['user','fld'], how='left')
df_result = df_result.withColumn('prev_idB', 
                         when(df_result.type == 'A', df_result.prev_idB))

df_result.show()
```

then you get

```
user | type | fld | time | idA | idB | prev_idB
jo      B      4    1:00  ---   454   ---
jo      A      4    1:01  302   ---   454
jo      B      3    1:02  ---   123   ---
jo      B      6    2:34  ---   345   ---
jo      A      3    4:33  764   ---   123
bob     B      2    1:02  ---   965   ---
bob     A      2    1:10  502   ---   965
```